# Rails: NameError (uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a problem with my rails app. I get the following Error:

```
NameError (uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique)
```

Im not sure why this is as it works on my development environment. The exception gets tested by:

> ```
>     begin
>       ...
>     rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique
>       next
>     end
> ```

Lg Markus

Comment: Where exactly is the code causing the exception? In a controller, an initializer, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When are you seeing this problem i.e. test, production?

What version of ActiveRecord do you have on this environment?

#### Update:

As far as I am aware ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique became available in version 3.0.0 onwards [apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/RecordNotUnique](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/RecordNotUnique) You need to have this version or greater to use this database exception.

Comment: Its in production mode and the version of AcriveRecord should be 2.3.2

Comment: As far as I am aware ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique became available in version 3.0.0 onwards

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/RecordNotUnique

You need to have this version or greater to use this database exception.

Comment: Editing your comment into the answer so it's displayed a bit more prominently.  This has been flagged as "not an answer" when really it is.

Comment: Thanks will remember to do this from now on